# Need ant script for sudo type installation of software

Tags: java, ant, exec, sudo

I need to write Ant build script to install software in linux env.
I have written something like

```
<exec dir="${dir}" executable="/bin/sh">
    <arg value="installsoftware.sh"/>
</exec>
```

But the problem I get "You must have administrator or root privilege to execute". I need  to run the installation with Sudo and give password to execute installsoftware.sh.

Can someone help me on writing ant script to invoke sudo type installations?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about turning the tables and sudo into a root and running installation as a root, i.e.

```
sudo ant -f /path/to/build.xml install
```

Comment: Hey Alexander, Sorry If i didnt give correct info. I need to write ant script and to install a software in linux env. the ant script is ran from client machine which is Windows Os. Everything is running fine except " administrator or root privilege". I need to write Ant script in a way that install software with sudo permission given the password. (the password can be hard coded in ant script)

Comment: @coolgokul.  I don't see how you can `exec` Linux program from your Windows client.  If you, somehow, connect to Linux client in your Ant script (e.g. through `sshexec`), then you can pass a `sudo` command to it.  In this case modify sudoers not to prompt for password, when `installsoftware.sh` is running from the dedicated account with installation priviledges.